# How to access overlay argument in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay

I have the following code in the Google Maps API javascript v2:

```
mylistener = GEvent.addListener(map2,'click',mapClick); 
...... 
...... 

function mapClick(section, clickedPoint){ 
   .... 
   if (section == null)) 
   .... 
}
```

As you can see, I use the argument section in my application.

In the Google Maps API javascript v3, I have:

`google.maps.event.addListener(map2, 'click', mapClick);`

`function mapClick(`???

I tried this in v2, but it doesn't work. I can only access the location of the clicked point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the event to each individual overlay.

```
var markers = [
    {lat: -25.363882, lon: 131.044922, title: "foo"},
    {lat: -26.363882, lon: 130.044922, title: "bar"},
];

//event callback
function callback(overlay, event) {
    console.log(overlay, event);
}

//add the markers
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     markers[i].obj = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lon), 
        map:      map,
        title:    markers[i].title
    });
    //closure
    (function(marker){
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            callback(marker, event);
        });
    })(marker[i].obj);
}
```

note: I didn't test this code